# Отправка HTTP-запросов из MySQL

Tags: mysql, http, триггер, airflow

В данный момент работаю над дипломной работой, цель которой построить и сравнить различные способы построения CDC (change data capture). Один из методов, которые я хочу попробовать, использование триггеров.

Задумка следующая:

1. Имеется таблица в OLTP БД (например, MySQL), в которой относительно не часто происходят изменения (вставка, обновление, удаление);
2. Имеется аналогичная таблица в, например, OLAP БД (например, ClickHouse);
3. Имеется Apache Airflow, в котором создан DAG, пишущий принимаемые значения в ClickHouse.

Я бы хотел узнать, есть ли возможность написать такой триггер в MySQL для этой таблицы таким образом, чтобы при ивенте отправлялся HTTP POST запрос в Apache Airflow с типом ивента и значениями, которые были изменены/записаны/удалены из таблицы, чтобы Python/SQLOperator записывал данные в ClickHouse?

В моём представлении это выглядит примерно таким образом:

```
CREATE TRIGGER http_trigger
AFTER UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
--Отправка запроса
    DECLARE response_body TEXT;
    SELECT http_request('https://airflow/api/dags/update_users_table', 'POST', CONCAT('event_type=', event_type, 'user_id=', NEW.user_id, ...)) INTO response_body;
-- Обработка ответа
...
END;
```

Поиск информации дал понять, что это возможно лишь скомпилировав user defined function на C, но, боюсь, мои знания C (а точнее, их отсутствие) сделают процесс мучительным и затянутым.

Буду рад ответам и/или советам!

Comment: Таких штатных инструментов в MySQL не существует. В принципе не существует. Только внешний модуль и user-defined procedure, которая выполняет указанную функцию. Хотя длинная операция в триггере - сродни [censored]. И куда как разумнее просто класть необходимые данные в очередь, а выгребать их оттуда и слать HTTPS совсем другим процессом.

Comment: @Akina что вы имеете в виду под "длинной операцией"? И под очередью вы подразумеваете топик в брокере сообщений?

Спасибо за то, что немного разъяснили ситуацию!

Comment: *что вы имеете в виду под "длинной операцией"?* операцию, занимающую много времени. Представляешь - операция занимает секунду, а запрос апдейтит тысячу записей... как итог - выполняется более чем четверть часа. *под очередью вы подразумеваете топик в брокере сообщений?* В MySQL нет никаких очередей и брокеров. И их надо организовывать самому. Я же имел в виду, что триггер просто складывает соотв. данные в таблицу, а внешний процесс, выполняемый по крону, вычитывает эту таблицу и выполняет необходимые отправки.